# Are There Any Security Issues In The Following File Upload Script - PHP

Tags: php, file, security, file-upload

I've looked at a number of the answers to StackOverflow questions on safely uploading images with PHP. I've put this following script together with explainers and wanted to know if this is missing anything. My only/main concern is I can't seem to find much info on stripping out harmful code from the image itself, although this is partly covered in the code.

A couple of SO answers touch on the `GD` image functionality but they don't really give any good code example cases and because I'm new to php I can't quite seem to wrap my head around how to use this (in terms of creating a new version of the image).

**Note:** This images in this code go to an '/images' directory, but on the live site they will go into a subdomain called 'images' which is outside the public folder and which will serve static files only (no PHP, Perl etc). The `short_open_tag` will be turned off in the php.ini file.

The files are selected with a `file` input type with the name 'profile-image'.

The following code is split into its component parts - the first part is the if/isset statements that check that a submit button called 'submit-profile-image' has been clicked, and the files have been uploaded into memory in the `['tmp_name']` key of the `$_FILES` superglobal:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-profile-image'])) {

    $allowed = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'];

    if($_FILES['profile-image']['error'] === 0 ) { 

        // THE DIFFERENT CHECKS IN THE MAIN CODE BELOW GO HERE

    } else {
        $error[] = "Image failed to load please try again";
    }
}
```

This following code all goes inside the 2nd if statement shown above - I've broken it down to show what it is meant to acheive:

Set variable names of temp upload file and file input name

```
$profileImageName = $_FILES['profile-image']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['profile-image']['tmp_name'];
```

Explode string to split the file name and file extension

```
$ext = explode('.', $profileImageName);
$ext = strtolower(end($ext));
```

Completely rename file, and only keep the file extension from the original file:

```
$file = uniqid('', true) . time() . '.' . $ext;
```

Sanitize string for extra safety (probably not needed)

```
$file = filter_var($file, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$file = strtolower($file);
```

Check the file extention matches the allowed array of file extensions:

```
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    $error[] = "File type must be in the jpg / jpeg or png format";
}
```

Check MIME type using the `getImageSize()` function which is more reliable than the 'type' key found in the standard $_FILES superglobal:

```
$getImageSizeMime = getImageSize($temp);

if(isset($getImageSizeMime['mime']) == false) {
    $error[] = "Not a recognised MIME type";
} else {
    $getImageSizeMime = $getImageSizeMime['mime'];
}
```

Make sure the MIME type matches the file extension:

```
if (in_array($ext, $allowed) != $getImageSizeMime) {
    $error[] = "Mime type must be of the jpg / jpeg or png format";
}
```

Inspect contents of image file itself:

```
$cleanUpload = file_get_contents($temp) ;
```

Disallow if file contents contain `php` or `script`:

```
if(preg_match('/(<\?php\s)/', $cleanUpload)) {
    $error[] = "Image data cannot contain php script tags";
}

if(preg_match('/script/', $cleanUpload)) {
    $error[] = "Image data cannot contain javascript tags";
}
```

Sanitise file contents of HTML tags

```
$cleanUpload = filter_var($cleanUpload, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Move uploaded file if none of the above errors are present

```
if (!isset($error)) {
    if(in_array($ext, $allowed)) {

        move_uploaded_file($temp, 'images/' . $file);

    }
}
```

Any input on any security issues missed or any extra checks on the image file itself would be hugely appreciated - particularly on how to duplicated the image to only keep image data using the GD library if possible/necessary? Some of the answers on StackOverflow are very old and seem to feature methods that aren't seen as the most up to date either (which I've avoided in this question).

It would be really good to see if there are any PHP methods for checking image files themselves and removing potentially dangerous code.

Comment: Running FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING on a genuine image file risks corrupting the file.

Comment: _"checking image files themselves and removing potentially dangerous code"_ You shouldn't need to be terribly concerned about image contents unless you're trying to execute the image file. You could use GD or ImageMagick to read the file and then re-write it, thus insuring it's a valid image.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - I did worry about that. It hasn't done so on any of the (many) images I tried in a batch upload, but will most likely omit that from the final code.

Comment: Also @AlexHowansky what do you mean by `unless you're trying to execute the image file` ? The images are going to be either used in a user profile, or stored in a gallery & the gallery images are going to be downloadable for users via a download button. So I guess that does mean executable?

Comment: If there is "malicious code" in a file, and the file is named like an image, and you save it on your server, and serve it to users via an `IMG` tag, then all they'll get is a broken image icon. The only way a "malicious" image can hurt you is if you do something like `require` or `shell_exec` on it.